# InstallAllUsers=0 not working for command line Python interpreter install on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to follow the [documented process for installing Python on Windows without associated UI](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui).

Using `c:\path\to\exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1` is not working.

When you run the UI install, you can deselect the option for all users which does not require admin rights to install. On my computer, the above works, on others computers, it does not.

The all users check box is defaulted to checked (or `1`) when I first double click on the .exe; so using the `InstallAllUsers=0` in the command line should disable or set to `0` right?

Comment: Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installing-without-ui). Trying to provide new version of Python using command line install params.

Comment: Thank you; I've edited the question to include that link, and otherwise be a bit more explicit about context.

Comment: According to the docs you posted, `0` is the default. When you say it is not working, what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: @MattClark If I opened the .exe by double clicking, the option to install for all users is set to checked (its a check box). So I am trying to use command line to set that to false.

Answer (score 1):

Was just struggling with this for the latest Python 3.10.7 installer on Windows 10.

You also need to tell it not to install the launcher for all users with `InstallLauncherAllUsers=0` since it defaults to 1.

Full command for OP should be:
`c:\path\to\exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=0 InstallLauncherAllUsers=0 PrependPath=1`

What helped me figure it out was reading the install logs in %temp% and I saw it setting `InstallLauncherAllUsers` to `1`

Answer (score -1):

I dont use windows really often but it seems that the default option for **InstallAllUsers** is **0**

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

have you tried without this flag ?

Comment: Yes, trying without the flag it is auto-set to all users. So if I double click the .exe, it opens up preselected.